# Loading a InMemory compiled assembly into current domain

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, assemblies, assembly-loading

I'm using `CSharpCodeProvider` to compile an assembly and I have the `CompileParameters` `GenerateInMemory` property set to `true` because I don't want to create a physical file.

After the compile I can take the `CompilerResults` and do something like this:-

```
 object x = cr.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("MyGeneratedClass");
 Console.WriteLine(x);
```

I get the expected output, the `CreateInstance` has worked.

However I need to be able to access types in the current `AppDomain` without such knowledge of the assembly.  I need to do something like this:-

```
 Type t = Type.GetType("MyGeneratedClass");
 object x = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

The problem is in this code `t` ends up being null.  Now I suspect that although the assembly is compiled it isn't loaded.  I can't seem to find away to load this assembly into the domain so that its type names can be resolved.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid that is explicitly impossible.

The [documentation for Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) clearly states:

*If the assembly has not been saved to disk when GetType is called, the method returns null. GetType does not understand transient dynamic assemblies; therefore, calling GetType to retrieve a type in a transient dynamic assembly returns null.*

You will have to write the assembly to disk if you want it to behave just like any regular assembly.

Comment: Selecting this as the answer since it lead me to the correct solution.  The name in GetType needs to be quailifed with the assembly name, which can be defined in the CompileParameters.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Cool! Glad I could be of help. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The GenerateInMemory property is a parlor trick.  The C# compiler doesn't know how to write to your program's memory.  It is faked, the compiler is asked to actually write the assembly to the TEMP directory.  From where it is loaded into memory after compilation succeeds with a FileStream into a byte[], then Assembly.Load(byte[]).  Have a look-see with Reflector, Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch() method.

Since it creates a file anyway, just not very visible, solve your problem by just letting it create a file and loading it in the AppDomain.

Comment: Thanks, I've got rid of GenerateInMemory but I'm now stuck on how to load the assembly, I'm using `Assembly.LoadFile` on `cr.PathToAssembly`.  However my call to `GetType` still returns null.

Comment: Avoid Assembly.LoadFile() like the plague, always use LoadFrom().  Note that you have the assembly now, you could open it in Reflector to have a look-see.  Otherwise hard to guess why GetType doesn't work.  Maybe you forgot the namespace or didn't make it public?  Also see what you get out of GetTypes().  And don't forget that you did this to get it loaded in another AppDomain.

Comment: Cancel the AppDomain remark, I was confuzzled about the question.  After you got it working you can set GenerateInMemory back to true.